# Получение файла GET запросом в python

Tags: python, rest

Сервер по GET запросу формирует csv в теле ответа на запрос, которую нужно сохранить в файл. При первом обращении, когда запрос сформирован верно, сервер отправляет код 200, после чего начинается формирование тела запроса. При последующем отправке запроса с одинаковым содержанием параметров возможны два варианта:

- файл еще формируется, код 200 и текстовое содержимое в виде процентов сформированной части ответа
- файл сформирован, код 202 и полный csv.
  Задача - сохранить csv в файл. Реализовал следущий скрипт на питоне.

```
import requests


def create_file(response):
    with open('file', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.text)


def create():

    url = '....csv'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'OAuth {token}',
        'content-disposition': 'attachment',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'text/csv'

    }
    params = {...
    }
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 202:
        create_file(response)


if name == '__main__':
    create()
```

Такой код отрабатывает, проблема в том, что этот скрипт нужно запускать до тех пор, пока ответ `response.status_code` будет равен 202. Полагаю, что можно завернуть логику в бесконечный генератор и запускать его в цикле до тех пор, пока не придет нужный ответ. Думаю, что более изысканным будет решение с потоками.
Как можно решить такую задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну просто ждите в бесконечном цикле, пока файл на сервере сформируется:

```
while True:
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 202:
        create_file(response)
        break
```

Можно ещё `time.sleep(сколько-нибудь)` в цикл добавить, чтобы не дёргать сервер слишком часто.

Comment: У меня примерно такая же идея была с time.sleep. Вы красиво оформили. Спасибо
Мне очень понравилась идея с реализацией логики в потоках.  Я понимаю, что это лишне. Но было бы красиво на мой взгляд.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян Если ваш код должен ещё что-то делать параллельно, тогда можно применить потоки либо асинхронное программирование :)  А если больше никаких задач у него нет, тогда потоки смысла не имеют - ваш код и так выполняется отдельным процессом